# How to manage third-party app windows in Linux?

Tags: window-manager, window-management

I want to manipulate the windows on a user's desktop.

For example moving a window to a new position, or getting a list of all windows and their titles.

I'm looking for the Linux-equivalent of win32's [`winuser.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/api/_winmsg/) and macOS's [Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services?language=objc).

Comment: Check out the command `xdotool`

Comment: `wmctrl` is also an option.

Comment: Sadly, it depends! Are you using X11 or Wayland, and if the latter, which desktop environment?

Comment: And it kind of also depends on your use case. For example, what you describe sounds like it could integrate nicely into gnome, but might make less sense on a different window managing approach like awesome-wm; in which case you'd want to write a gnome-shell extension (which of course would fit nicely with the rest of gnome, but be useless for anyone not using gnome).

Comment: I want to make a sidebar that slides in and out like Microsoft's Edge Bar (https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-edge-bar-sidebar-office-bar-explained), and be able to move third-party windows around.